# Change the shape of list with multiple arrays python

Tags: python, list, shapes, training-data, conv-neural-network

Initially, I had a dictionary named `voltage` with 206 arrays each of the shape `(25,3,1)`. I have converted the dictionary into a list of arrays using the following code

```
temp = []
input= []

for value, key in voltage.items():
    temp = [key,value]
    input.append(temp)
```

`input` is the name of my list. When I check the shape of the list, I get `(1,206,2)`

```
np.shape(input) - gives (1,206,2)
```

I want to change the shape of the list to `(206, 25,3,1)`. When I pass the `input` to the following model I get an error (attached below).

```
K = Input(shape=(25,3,1))

x = Conv2D(16,(2,2), strides=2, activation='relu', data_format='channels_last', padding='same')(K)   
x = BatchNormalization()(x)

x = Conv2D(32,(2,2), activation='relu', data_format='channels_last' , padding='same')(x)  
x = BatchNormalization()(x)

x = Flatten()(x)

x = Dense(320, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(160, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(80, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(1)(x)

model = Model(K,x)

model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mse')

model.fit(x=input, y=output, steps_per_epoch=None, epochs=1000)
```

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_5 to have 4
> dimensions, but got array with
> (1, 206, 2) shape

Would appreciate some help.

Comment: A few comments: an array of size (N, 3, 1) doesn't seem to make sense, you should probably flattern the last level and make it of shape (N, 3): `[[[0], [1], [2]], [[1], [2], [3]], [[2], [3], [4]], ...]` -> `[[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], ...]`. Also, you seem to have the key and the value in the wrong order at the start: `for key, value in voltage.items():`

Comment: Following your steps, `np.shape(input)` returns `(206, 2)` not `(1, 206, 2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
import numpy as np

d = {1: np.random.rand(25, 3, 1),
2: np.random.rand(25, 3, 1),
3: np.random.rand(25, 3, 1),
4: np.random.rand(25, 3, 1)}

arr = np.empty((len(d.keys()), *d[1].shape))

for i, k in enumerate(d.keys()):
    arr[i] = d[k]

print(arr.shape)  # (4, 25, 3, 1)
```

Create an empty `numpy` array in the desired size, and then append the dict, `volatge`, value to the desired position.

If your keys are not regular (meaning 1, 4, 6 etc) you could create a map that maps the first entry of the `arr` to the `voltage` value.

Comment: Thank you so much @David . It worked. Please share a link if any,  where I can get kind of documentation related to this. I would like to know more about this. Thank you :D

Comment: @PradyumnaTK Documentation about what? numpy arrays?

Comment: About converting dictionaries into lists, arrays, etc, and accessing the items in them. If you have any please share. Else its fine, Ill check them out :) @David

Comment: @PradyumnaTK There is no "source" for it, it mostly practices.